# "Could not determine API level for $(TargetFrameworkVersion) of 'v13.0' ". Error during Build after SDK Update from API Level 31 to 33

Tags: android, xamarin, jenkins, build

I am working on this project which is an Android App, I had to update the SDK Version of Android, and these are the changes I made.
[Android TargetFramework Upgrade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9r4sD.png)
[Android Target Android Version Upgrade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WxjQ.png)
I managed to build the project using Visual Studio Code, but the client using Jenkins build pipe received this error:

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(265,5): error XA0000: Could not determine API level for $(TargetFrameworkVersion) of 'v13.0'.

Any ideas how to fix this problem? Thanks a lot.

I tried to manually change in the .csproj file of the .Droid project from version v12.0 to v13.0, because when I updated the TargetFramework in the Properties this value remained v12.0 instead of 13.0 at line 31, unfortunately with no results.
[Line 31 TargetFrameworkVersion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FgUS.png)

Comment: You can try to add `<AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>True</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>` in the .csproj file and build it again.